# Retopology mesh experiencing errors while moving / deleting original mesh

Tags: mesh, sculpting, topology, retopology

I am a beginner at Blender. This sculpture is my very first.

I have completed the sculpture and retopology.

This is the **sculpture**: https://twitter.com/DariaWinnicka/status/1516069031673012224

This is the **retopology**: https://twitter.com/DariaWinnicka/status/1575455988655734786

During retopology, I followed this step-by-step video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuQzPDs99yM&list=WL&index=32&t=605s

**Problem:**

- I'd like to delete the original mesh from the file (I create a copy of the file after each stage is completed - the last stage was retopology).
- However, if I move or delete the original mesh, the retopology mesh experiences errors.

**Please watch the video to understand further:** https://youtu.be/6YHAv5M-hbU

I appreciate all the help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply (Ctrl A) the shrinkwrap modifier before moving the original sculpt.

Comment: I applied all modifiers (inc. shrinkwrap + mirror + subdivide) and that worked wonderfully: https://youtu.be/1qRH7xmCRCc
I appreciate your help very much, thank you.

Comment: Subdivide modifier is better to mantain unapplied, generally speaking.

Comment: I was able to return to the previous stage and keep the subdivision modifier unapplied. That's very helpful of you, thank you.